# use named regex groups to output an array of matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the hang of named capturing groups.

Given a string

```
var a = '{hello} good {sir}, a [great] sunny [day] to you.';
```

I'd like to output an array which maintains the integrity of the sentence (complete with punctuation, spaces, etc) so I can reassemble the sentence at a later time:

```
[
  {
    group: "braces",
    word: "hello"
  },
  {
    group: "other",
    word: " good " <-- space on either side is maintained
  },
  {
    group: "braces",
    word: "sir"
  },
  {
    group: "other",
    word: ", a "
  },
  {
    group: "brackets",
    word:  "great"
  },
  {
    group: "other",
    word: " sunny "
  },
  {
    group: "brackets",
    word: "day"
  },
  {
    group: "other",
    word:  " to you."
  },
]
```

I'm using [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) to try and output this. `<braces>` captures any text within `{}`, `<brackets>` captures any text within `[]`, and `<others>` captures anything else (`\s,.\w+`):

```
var regex = /(?<braces>\{(.*?)\})(?<brackets>\[(.*?)\])(?<others>\s,.\w+)?/g;
```

`console.log(a.match(regex));` outputs nothing.

If I remove `<others>` group,

```
var regex = /(?<braces>\{(.*?)\})(?<brackets>\[(.*?)\])?/g;
```

`console.log(a.match(regex));` outputs `["{hello}", "{sir}"]`

**Question**: How do I use capturing groups to find all instances of named groups and output them like the above desired array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex match object will only contain *one* string for a given named capture group. For what you're trying to do, you'll have to do it in two steps: first separate out the parts of the input, then map it to the array of objects while checking which group was captured to identify the sort of `group` it needs:

```js
const str = '{hello} good {sir}, a [great] sunny [day] to you.';
const matches = [...str.matchAll(/{([^{]+)}|\[([^\]]+)\]|([^[{]+)/g)]
  .map(match => ({
    group: match[1] ? 'braces' : match[2] ? 'brackets' : 'other',
    word: match[1] || match[2] || match[3]
  }));
  
console.log(matches);
```